# Is it possible to access variable of one jsp (Application A) in another jsp(Application B)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

Considering I have two different applications, A and B
and each having their own jsp, a.jsp and b.jsp
Next,

1.I will set one session in application A

2.Redirect to application B and set one session in Application B

3.Again redirect to application A

4.Now, I will check session in application A and it will exist

-session will also exist in application B

5.In b.jsp I will set a flag based on the session(exits or not)

Is it possible to access that flag variable in a.jsp?
Without using JavaScript or ServletContext  or a common database

Comment: That's why web services exist... so that 2 applications can communicate with each other

Comment: An also to share methods between apps without the need to rewrite the whole methods or recreate the whole configuration ...

Comment: Tried it, It destroys the session in the applications @Noblesse

Comment: Have you checked if it's related to the session configuration ?

Comment: Yes I did. Its nowhere related to session configuration

Comment: Basically you want to open 2 sessions in 2 different apps but it's not working ?
It's not well explained

Comment: Yes, first in A, then in B and then on every load, 
check if the session in B exits from A ( For the verifying only I need the variable to be shared )